# Kafka python consumers running in parallel threads

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I'm a total newbie in python and kafka. I have a script that should start three kafka consumers, wait for messages from those consumers and do some other things. At this point I don't even know if I'm going in the right direction so any help will be appreciated.

```
class MainClass():
    def do_something_before(self):
        # something is done here

    def start_consumer(self):
        consumer1_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.cons1, args=())
        consumer2_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.cons2, args=())
        consumer1_thread.daemon = True
        consumer2_thread.daemon = True
        consumer1_thread.start()
        consumer2_thread.start()

    def cons1(self):
        consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092',
                                 auto_offset_reset='earliest')
        consumer.subscribe(['my-topic'])
        for message in consumer:
            print(message.value)

    def cons2(self):
        consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092',
                                 auto_offset_reset='earliest')
        consumer.subscribe(['my2-topic'])
        for message in consumer:
            print(message.value)

    def keep_working(self):
        # something is done here

if __name__ == 'main':
    g = MainClass()
    g.do_something_before()
    g.keep_working()
```

Comment: Can you be clearer what you're asking us to help with here please. Do you get an error? Is the code not behaving how you expect? If so, what are you expecting and what are you observing?

Answer (score 7):

I have added python-kafka example with 2 consumers(basically two python processes), you can find it on github link here https://github.com/Shubhamgorde/kafka-python-app.

Cant post the entire python files, its little big.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def consumeData(topic):
    try:
         consumer = KafkaConsumer(topic, value_deserializer=lambda v: 
           binascii.unhexlify(v).decode('utf-8'))
    except:
         print("Error!!")

    for msg in consumer:
        msg=ast.literal_eval(msg.value)
        if(msg[2] == 'C'):
            performCreditOperation(msg)
        elif (msg[2] == 'D'):
              performDebitOperation(msg)

t1 = Process(target=consumeData, args=('Credit_transac',))
t2 = Process(target=consumeData, args=('Debit_transac',))
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my Implementation. Hope you find it useful.

```
class ConsumerThread:
    def __init__(self, config, topics):
        self.config = config
        self.topics = topics

    def readData(self):
        consumer = Consumer(self.config)
        consumer.subscribe(self.topics)
        self.run(consumer)

    def process_msg(self, msg):
        print('Received message.')
        print('Key: {}, Val: {}'.format(msg.key(), msg.value()))
        print('Partition: {}, Offset: {}'.format(msg.partition(), msg.offset()))

    def run(self, consumer):
        try:
            while True:
                msg = consumer.poll(0.1)
                if not msg:
                    continue
                if msg.error():
                    if msg.error().code() == KafkaError._PARTITION_EOF:
                        # End of partition event
                        print('End of partition reached {0}/{1}'
                            .format(msg.topic(), msg.partition()))
                    else:
                        raise KafkaException(msg.error())
                else:
                    self.process_msg(msg)

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Detected Keyboard Interrupt. Cancelling.")
            pass

        finally:
            consumer.close()
```